# How many pairs of prime number $(p,q)$ so that $p-q$ is a square number?

Tags: number-theory

How many pairs of prime number $(p,q)$ so that $p-q$ is a square number ? Moreover, how many pairs of prime number $(p,q)$ so that $p-q$ is a $k$th power of a number or a power of $n$ with $k,n \geq  2$ ?

Comment: By a power of $k$, did you mean a $k$th power? Your first question would then be a special case of your second.

Comment: Many problems in Number Theory easily proposing but quite difficult to solving.

Answer (score 2):

It is conjectured that for every even positive integer $d$ there are infinitely many pairs of primes $p,q$ with $p-q=d$.  However, this is still open, as are your questions.

See [OEIS sequence A065376](https://oeis.org/A065376) for primes of the form $p+k^2$
and [OEIS sequence A065380](https://oeis.org/A065381) for primes of the form $p+2^k$.